# Put an object of the wrong type in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

Considering this piece of code, in which I have two maps, a `Map<String, Integer>` and a `Map<String, String>`. I assign the second one to an Object and cast this object to a Map so that I can putAll this map to the first one.

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("one", 1);
    Map<String, String> otherMap = new HashMap<>();
    otherMap.put("two", "two");

    Object obj = otherMap;

    map.putAll((Map<String,Integer>)obj);

    Assert.assertFalse(map.get("two") instanceof Integer);
    Assert.assertEquals("{one=1, two=two}", map.toString());
```

The first assert ensures that the second element of my Map is not a Integer, so how come the putAll did not fail ?
The second assert is jus here to show that there is no apparent problem to this map.
How can I make sure that the putAll method will fail, when the map is first assigned to an Object ?

Thanks

Comment: How to make sure: avoid casting. That's one of the main reasons to use generics in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are a *compile-time* feature, and are *not* enforced at runtime.  Your code would compile with unchecked warnings telling you exactly this: that your code might behave unexpectedly.

To massively oversimplify, all `Map`s are treated as a `Map<Object, Object>` at runtime.  (Not really, but sort of.)

Answer (score 0):

You could, if you really wanted, use [Collections.checkedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedMap(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)) to wrap the map and enforce the type-safety at runtime. There's an associated performance cost though.